# Can I publish AAR file is included another AAR file in /libs folder?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have been developing two applications, A and B and they use a “shared” library published on a Maven repository.

Inside the “shared” library project, there are some external libraries likes `“/libs/C.aar”` and connect dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
}
```

For using “shared” libraries in both applications, I published to Maven repository, added a dependency, and rebuilt the project. But there is no `aar` file inside the “shared” library.

Can I publish AAR file *(which is included another AAR file)* in `/libs` folder?

I asked the same thing in the Gradle forum too. 
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-i-publish-aar-file-is-included-another-aar-file-in-libs-folder/30074?u=skylershin

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to add 'dependencies' relation in your“shared” library  other than to add `aar` file into your “shared” library.

Try to use maven dependencies like `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`  to replace dependencies like this `compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')`  in your “shared” library.

If you still want to add `aar` file into your “shared” library.
Refer to this [android-fat-aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) whcih can combine your aar file into your library aar file includes class and resource.

And perhaps you need to control your gradle version if you use `android-fat-aar`

Comment: Yes. I tried `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])` statement and maybe that work same way with `compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')`.